# Buggy output from XML::Twig on a Tee

Tags: xml, perl, xml-parsing, xml-twig

I am trying to split an xml file into multiple well-formed fragments, and [an ancient PerlMonks solution](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=1106908) is doing pretty well what I am looking for with help of XML::Twig that spits into a Tee... at least with simple data input.

If I complicate a little bit the data structure by regrouping the nodes to filter into a parent node, the second file is not well formed: the parent node is missing its opening tag. And I am quite lost to find the cause.

SSCCE (the difference with initial example is the `<thing_list>` that contains the `<thing>`'s):

```
use XML::Twig;
use IO::Tee;
use feature 'say';

open my $frufile, '>', 'fruit.xml' or die "fruit $!";
open my $vegfile, '>', 'veg.xml' or die "veg $!";

my $tee = IO::Tee->new($frufile, $vegfile);
select $tee;

my $twig=XML::Twig->new(
    twig_handlers => {
        thing  => \&magic,
        _default_  => sub { 
            say STDOUT '_default_ for '.$_->name;
            $_[0]->flush($tee); #default filehandle = tee 
            1; 
        },
    },
    pretty_print => 'indented',
    empty_tags   => 'normal',
);

$twig->parse( *DATA );

sub magic {
    my ($thing, $element) = @_;
    say STDOUT "magic for ". $element->{att}{type};
    for ($element->{att}{type}) {
            if (/fruit/) {
                $thing->flush($frufile);
            } elsif (/vegetable/) {
                $thing->flush($vegfile);
            } else {
                $thing->purge;
            }
    }
    1;
}

__DATA__
<batch>
  <header>
    <foo>1</foo>
    <bar>2</bar>
    <baz>3</baz>
  </header>
  <thing_list>
  <thing type="fruit"     >Im an apple!</thing>
  <thing type="city"      >Toronto</thing>
  <thing type="vegetable" >Im a carrot!</thing>
  <thing type="city"      >Melrose</thing>
  <thing type="vegetable" >Im a potato!</thing>
  <thing type="fruit"     >Im a pear!</thing>
  <thing type="vegetable" >Im a pickle!</thing>
  <thing type="city"      >Patna</thing>
  <thing type="fruit"     >Im a banana!</thing>
  <thing type="vegetable" >Im an eggplant!</thing>
  <thing type="city"      >Taumatawhakatangihangakoauauotamateaturipukakapikimaungahoronukupokaiwhenuakitanatahu</thing>
  </thing_list>
  <trailer>
    <chrzaszcz>A</chrzaszcz>
    <zdzblo>B</zdzblo>
  </trailer>
</batch>
```

While the first `fruit.xml` is ok:

```
<batch>
  <header>
    <foo>1</foo>
    <bar>2</bar>
    <baz>3</baz>
  </header>
  <thing_list>
    <thing type="fruit">Im an apple!</thing>
    <thing type="fruit">Im a pear!</thing>
    <thing type="fruit">Im a banana!</thing>
  </thing_list>
  <trailer>
    <chrzaszcz>A</chrzaszcz>
    <zdzblo>B</zdzblo>
  </trailer>
</batch>
```

the `veg.xml` is missing an opening tag for `<thing_list>`

```
<batch>
  <header>
    <foo>1</foo>
    <bar>2</bar>
    <baz>3</baz>
  </header>
    <thing type="vegetable">Im a carrot!</thing>
    <thing type="vegetable">Im a potato!</thing>
    <thing type="vegetable">Im a pickle!</thing>
    <thing type="vegetable">Im an eggplant!</thing>
  </thing_list>
  <trailer>
    <chrzaszcz>A</chrzaszcz>
    <zdzblo>B</zdzblo>
  </trailer>
</batch>
```

I have also noticed that if I comment out the `<thing_list>` tags into the data, the comment corresponding to the opening tag is also missing from `veg.xml`, but not from `fruit.xml`...

I seem to understand that the first comment is coming while processing the first `<thing>` and the second should be processed from the `_default_` handler while processing the rest of the file. But I do not understand if it is the same while `<thing_list>` is not commented.

WFIW, I am using Strawberry's Perl 5.20.1 on a Windows 7 box

Comment: Can reproduce on Linux

Comment: @ikegami you meant "can not reproduce"?

Comment: No, there's no typo. I wrote what I meant.

Comment: @ikegami thanks for taking time to test. So it is either broken or more probably I misunderstand the usage of XML::Twig

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oh wow, I'm surprised that works as well as it does!

The first time you reach `$thing->flush($frufile);`, it prints everything before it that hasn't been flushed yet. If it wasn't for your earlier attempt to fix this, it would have output:

```
<batch>
  <header>
    <foo>1</foo>
    <bar>2</bar>
    <baz>3</baz>
  </header>
  <thing_list>
    <thing type="fruit">Im an apple!</thing>
```

With your attempt, it prints

```
  <thing_list>
    <thing type="fruit">Im an apple!</thing>
```

The subsequent times you call `magic`, `<thing_list>` and everything before it has already been printed, so it's not printed again.

Don't mix and match output handles! If you have two files to generate, process the template twice. (And get rid of that `_default_` twig handler.)

---

That said, switching from `twig_handlers` to `twig_roots` (which is better for large documents anyway) appears to work:

```
my $twig = XML::Twig->new(
    twig_roots => {
        'thing_list/thing' => sub {
            my ($t, $element) = @_;
            for ($element->{att}{type}) {
                if (/fruit/) {
                    $t->flush($frufile);
                } elsif (/vegetable/) {
                    $t->flush($vegfile);
                } else {
                    $t->purge;
                }
            }
        },
    },
    twig_print_outside_roots => 1,
    pretty_print => 'indented',
    empty_tags => 'normal',
);
```

Use at your own risk :)

Comment: So it is my understanding of the XML::Twig that needs to be fixed. Is the `<thing_list>` supposed to be given with the first `<thing>` as its parent? If so, I don't understand why it is not the case for all following calls to the `magic` handler.

Comment: No, your program needs to be fixed. Don't mix and match output handles. If you need to generate two files, run the template twice.

Comment: Oh, too bad. My actual case is to split into "smaller" chunks (30..200MB) a file that can be huge so I found that trick to output the header and footer parts at once in several files with the Tee and dispatch the rest with handlers was a clever solution for not having to read the file several times. I will probably try a SAX-based parsing instead.

Comment: @Seki, Updated my answer.

Comment: thanks, for your update. Now it's quite close to what I am trying to get, but it is producing sparse files: there are some empty lines with only indentation corresponding to discarded items, even with `pretty_print => 'none'`

Comment: Right, cause it's printing the text nodes between the `thing` elements you are deleting.

Comment: do you know a mean to prevent all that white spaces? If my initial doc is over 200MB this would still waste a lot of space in the splitted file.

Comment: Since you're concerned with space, but not with speed, just preprocess your XML.